# SQL like and concat not returning Values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The Query below does not return any value except i remove the  "And source like concat('%','','%')" . even if i pass parameters to the like clause, i still do not get any result.

```
    SELECT 
    *
FROM
    report r
WHERE
    DATE(r.txn_date) BETWEEN '2018-01-1' AND '2018-01-17'
        AND r.names LIKE CONCAT('%','','%')
        AND r.comments LIKE CONCAT('%', '','%')
        AND r.tid LIKE CONCAT('%','','%')
        AND r.source like concat('%','','%')
```

Comment: Remove one condition at the time and see when data starts to be returned. (Perhaps a null value in one of the columns.)

Comment: just guessing, but maybe the problem is with % and null values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910440/can-i-make-where-col-like-select-null-values-too

Comment: if i remove the last condition, then i get data

Comment: Then try `select * from report r where r.source is null`. Any rows returned?

Comment: Maybe you want something like `... and (r.source LIKE ... or r.source is null)`, for the different columns?

Comment: @jarlh if i run `select * from report r where r.source is null` i get rows

Comment: ...and "null value LIKE whatever" is not true.

Comment: even if i parse in a value like this `AND r.source like concat('%','POS','%')` i still do not get value. and if i also do something like this `select * from report r where r.source is not null` i get values

Comment: Thank you all for the support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i used two columns that contained null in my where clause. I had to set a default value for them before the above query could work.